# Creating a global variable in Talend to use as a filter in another component

Tags: mysql, sql-server, talend

I have job in Talend that is designed to bring together some data from different databases: one is a MySQL database and the other a MSSQL database.

What I want to do is match a selection of loan numbers from the MySQL database (about 82,000 loan numbers) to the corresponding information we have housed in the MSSQL database.

However, the tables in MSSQL to which I am joining the data from MySQL are much larger (~ 2 million rows), are quite wide, and thus cost much more time to query. Ideally I could perform an inner join between the two tables based on the loan number, but since they are in different databases this is not possible. The inner join that is performed inside a tMap occurs after the Lookup input has already returned its data set, which is quite large (especially since this particular MSSQL query will execute a user-defined function for each loan number).

Is there any way to create a global variable out of the output from the MySQL query (namely, the loan numbers selected by the MySQL query) and use that global variable as an IN clause in the MSSQL query?

Comment: Have you tried a linked server connection from SQL Server to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. I'm not working in MySQL but I have something roughly equivalent here that I think you should be able to adapt to your needs.

***I've never actually answered a Stackoverflow question and while I was typing this the page started telling me I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 pictures/links here and I think I need 4 pics, so I'm just going to write it out in words here and post the whole thing complete with illustrations [on my blog](https://thedataswarm.wordpress.com/2016/03/15/building-a-list-in-talend-to-use-as-a-filter-in-another-component/) in case you need more info (quite likely, I should think!)***

As you can see, I've got some data coming out of the table and getting filtered by tFilterRow_1 to only show the rows I'm interested in.

The next step is to limit it to just the field I want to use in the variable. I've used tMap_3 rather than a tFilterColumns because the field I'm using is a string and I wanted to be able to concatenate single quotes around it but if you're using an integer you might not need to do that. And of course if you have a lot of repetition you might also want to get a tUniqueRows in there as well to save a lot of unnecessary repetition

The next step is the one that does the magic. I've got a list like this:

- 'A1'
- 'A2'
- 'B1'
- 'B2'

etc, and I want to turn it into 'A1','A2','B1','B2' so I can slot it into my where clause. For this, I've used tAggregateRow_1, selecting "list" as the aggregate function to use.

Next up, we want to take this list and put it into a context variable (I've already created the context variable in the metadata - you know how to do that, right?). Use another tMap component, feeding into a tContextLoad widget. tContextLoad always has two columns in its schema, so map the output of the tAggregateRows to the "value" column and enter the name of the variable in the "key". In this example, my context variable is called MyList

Now your list is loaded as a text string and stored in the context variable ready for retrieval. So open up a new input and embed the variable in the sql code like this

> "SELECT distinct MY_COLUMN
>     from MY_SECOND_TABLE where the_selected_row in ("+
>   context.MyList+")"

It should be as easy as that, and when I whipped it up it worked first time, but let me know if you have any trouble and I'll see what I can do.